# cxGrid selection - avoid selecting one particular column

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4, tcxgrid, quantumgrid

When you select a row in the cxGrid, the entire row gets selected (changes color to blue).
How can I tell the grid not to select the records from a certain column i.e leave it colorless ? I tried afterscroll of the dataset to use :

```
cxGrid1dbTableView1.GetColumnByFieldName('MYFIELD').Focused := True;
```

But does not work.....

Comment: What ar you trying to achieve? Selecting only a few cells from a record? Or visually exclude columns from your selection? Because I don't think the grid is capable of selecting a few cells when you click on a row.

Comment: visually exclude column from my selection

Comment: Then use Stefan Glienke's answer, or a variation of that.

Comment: @ Roald van Doorn - I am using style for that particular column. I want to exclude it from the selection only. I cant change its style.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OnCustomDrawCell` event of the columns you want to change and put this code inside:

```
if AViewInfo.Selected then
begin
  ACanvas.Brush.Color := clWindow;
  ACanvas.Font.Color := clWindowText;
end;
```

In my case I am not using any theming so the colors match. If you are using something different you have to change them accordingly.

Comment: I am already using cxstyle for that field so I cant use OnCustomDrawCell. Thats the main reason I dont want the field selected because it does not display style text color properly when it's selected.

Comment: Where is the problem? Assign the Color and Font.Color of the assigned cxStyle then.

Comment: OnCustomDrawCell won't do much if you are using styles. I don't even know if it is still called. But you can override the OnGetContentStyle and just return a different style for the columns you wish to exclude.

Comment: @RoaldvanDoorn I think you are confusing style and skin. If you are using a style (TcxStyle) the OnCustomDrawCell is still called. But it may not when using skinning.

Comment: @ Stefan Glienke - you cant assign style to canvas.

Comment: No joke... but you can assign the color of the style to the color of the brush of the canvas.

Comment: Or you could override the OnGetContentStyle of your columns and return a proper defined style with different colors.